# prove $ e^{bt} \ \int_0^t \ f(s) ds=\int_0^t \ ( e^{-bs} \ f(s)-be^{-bs}\int_0^s\ f(u)\ du) \ ds $

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral

please How can I prove that
$$
e^{-bt} \ \int_0^t \ f(s) ds=\int_0^t \ ( e^{-bs} \ f(s)-be^{-bs}\int_0^s\ f(u)\ du) \ ds
$$ 
f non-negative  measurable function

I would appreciate it enormously if anyone could help
best,educ

Comment: We would also appreciate that you put a little effort in your questions before spamming us with them.

Comment: i'm so sorry but i did my best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first Thank you dear professor for ur time

so we know that : 
$$(fg)'=  f'(s).g(s)ds +f(s).g'(s)ds $$
$$\int_0^t(fg)'=(fg)= \int_0^t \ f'(s).g(s)ds +\int_0^tf(s).g'(s)ds$$
so we use that for the left-side term :
$$ e^{-bt} \ \int_0^t \ f(s)ds$$ with $u(s)=e^{-bs}, v(s)=\int_0^s f(u)du ,u'(s)=-be^{-bs},v'(s)=f(s)ds$
now it's easy to see :
$e^{-bt} \ \int_0^t \ f(s)ds=u(t)v(t)=\int_0^t \ u'(s).v(s)ds +\int_0^tu(s).v'(s)ds=\int_0^t \ ( e^{-bs} \ f(s)-be^{-bs}\int_0^s\ f(u)\ du) \ ds$
you see the details make anyone able to understand, that's why i love the details 
best regrads , Educ

Answer (score 2):

Try differentiating both sides.

Comment: please can you be more specific by writing that in details

Comment: Sorry, no. You can do it: Both sides are a function of one variable only, namely $t$. Surely, you can perform the differentiation yourself? Do you know the fundamental theorem of calculus?